# ViewPager and Menu-Items and WebViews

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-webview, android-viewpager, menuitem

Is there a way to create my Menu Items for the actionbar in my MainActivity where my ViewPager is created so that way im only creating my webview items (back, forward and refresh buttons) once. Then inside my onOptions.... Then specify the menu items to be able to handle my webview.

All my fragments in my ViewPager are webviews, i just want 3 constant Actionbar items to control the webview's that is being shown. Instead of recreating them each time my viewpager loads another fragment. Any Idea's???

### Fragment

```
public class Fragment1 extends SherlockFragment {
    WebView web;
    static ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inf, ViewGroup grp, Bundle icicle) {
        View v = inf.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, grp, false);
        web = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        //Now i know that i need this to use MENU ITEMS in this fragment
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        //
        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        web.setWebViewClient(new SpecialWebView(progressBar));
        web.setWebChromeClient(new SpecialWebChromeClient(progressBar));
        // Progress Bar - End

        WebSettings websettings = web.getSettings();
        websettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        web.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f2f2f2"));
        websettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        websettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        websettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        websettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        websettings.setSavePassword(true);
        web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");   
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater Inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        Inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem Item) {
        final int current = ((ViewPager) mFragments).getCurrentItem();
        String currentId = current == 0 ? FRAGMENT1: (current == 1 ? FRAGMENT2: FRAGMENT3);
        //WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(currentId);
        switch (Item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_back:
            web.goBack();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_forward:
            web.goForward();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_refresh:
            web.reload();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(Item);
    }
```

### MainActivity

```
  public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
private ViewPager mPager;
private TitlePageIndicator mIndicator;
private MainPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private List<Fragment> mFragments;

private static final String FRAGMENT1 = Fragment1.class.getName();
private static final String FRAGMENT2 = Fragment2.class.getName();
private static final String FRAGMENT3 = SupportFragment.class.getName();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.a_main);

    // add fragments
    mFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    mFragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FRAGMENT1));
    mFragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FRAGMENT2));
    mFragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FRAGMENT3));

    // adapter
    mAdapter = new MainPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mFragments);

    // pager
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // indicator
    mIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.title_indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a main layout xml file, and put the 'static' buttons there. Then in the area you want to have a ViewPager you just drop a ViewPager. (depending on your layout the buttons could be above/below/over/beside the ViewPager)Then in code you pass through references (possible weak references depending on what you need) of the buttons ***if*** the fragments need to know about them.

The other way I read this (I was unclear exactly what you wanted) you can simply create a options menu for the activity, and then when the options item is selected, just call the correct method in the activity or the active fragment. You can keep track of the active fragment by `implements OnPageChangeListener`

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but it likely is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just move your `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()` implementations from the fragment to the activity.

In `onOptionsItemSelected()` get a reference to the `WebView` of the currently active fragment, e.g. by adding a `getWebView()` method to your fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You need the onPageChangeListener:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html

Maintain a reference to the currently selected fragment, then change the reference to the active one in onPageChangeListener.onPageSelected() based on position.

From that on it's should not be too hard to get a reference to the widgets in the fragment. As cketti mentioned, you will have to move onOptionsItemSelected() to the activity.